# P5.JS: Saving generative art (using noise()) as images on device and reuploading them on HTML

Tags: canvas, p5.js, noise, perlin-noise, generative-art

I'm working on generative art using p5.js and the `noise()` function. I have followed Daniel Shiffman's tutorials, but his final product always ends up being in constant generation, like an everlasting animation.

On my end, I'd like to save these auto-generated canvases as images on my device. I guess there'll be problems in my idea because these shapes are generated in time, and wanting them as still images would deny them their generation process?

To be more precise: without counting the database side of  this project on which I'll eventually work (My guess is that the program should first create these 6 shapes and save them as images and then upload them again on the html page), I'd like an html page to have 6 different images of auto-generated shapes.

My code:

```
var inc;



function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 800);
  background(0);
  noFill();
  t = 0;
}

function draw() {
  var r = 255 * noise(t+10);
  var g = 255 * noise(t+15);
  var b = 255 * noise(t+20);
  stroke(r,g,b, 18);
  strokeWeight(2);
  fill(r,g,b,5);
  var x1 = width * noise(t);
  var x2 = width * noise(t+1);
  var x3 = width * noise(t+2);
  var x4 = width * noise(t+3);
  var y1 = height * noise(t+4);
  var y2 = height * noise(t+5);
  var y3 = height * noise(t+6);
  var y4 = height * noise(t+7);

  quad(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4);
  t += 0.01;


  //noLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply right-click the canvas and save what's currently displayed as an image.

Or you could use one of the `save*()` functions in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/). The `save()` function or the `saveCanvas()` functions would be a good place to start. The `saveFrames()` function can save short animations.

Or you could look into using a library like [ccapture.js](https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js/) or a tool like [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/) if you want to store an animated file.

You might also consider simply drawing an unanimated canvas. Hard-code the values you want, and then use [instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode) to show multiple static sketches.

Which approach you take depends entirely on how you want your program to behave. I'd recommend trying a few different approaches out and seeing which one you like the best.